# Create / import hive table using Sqoop

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop

When I use below import command it allows me to create table and import data from mysql to Hive and I can see the table "widgets" in Hive.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hadoopguide --table widgets --username <username> --password <password> --split-by id -m 1 --hive-import;
```

But whenever I use below "create-hive-table" command, I get an error.

Command:

```
sqoop create-hive-table --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hadoopguide --table widgets --username <username> --password <password> --fields-terminated-by ',';
```

Error:

> 17/03/14 21:30:21 INFO hive.HiveImport: FAILED: Execution Error,
>   return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient 17/03/14 21:30:21
>   ERROR tool.CreateHiveTableTool: Encountered IOException running create
>   table job: java.io.IOException: Hive exited with status 1     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeExternalHiveScript(HiveImport.java:385)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeScript(HiveImport.java:335)
>     at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.tool.CreateHiveTableTool.run(CreateHiveTableTool.java:58)
>     at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)     at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)   at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)    at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)    at
>   org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)

Can anyone please assist me why I am getting this error.
Any input from your side will be great :-) .

Comment: I think your Hive metastore service is not running.

Comment: your code looks good verify whether service is running or not

Comment: my all services / daemons are running. What is Hive metastore service and what is command to run this?

Answer (score 0):

Is you Hadoop Services running.

$ start-all.sh

hive> show database;